# Xcode launch screen minimising whenever I try to open project

Tags: xcode

I have been using the latest Xcode for weeks now with no issues. Today I tried to launch Xcode and was met with a bouncing icon which ultimately got no further.

So I restarted my Mac and tried again, this time with success, I got as far as the launch screen

Now what I have is I try to open the project that I was using yesterday (I have tried other projects) and the launch screen disappears.... and nothing happens, if I click Xcode's icon in the launch bar (along the bottom) the launch screen reappears.

Xcode is not closing so it's not crashing as far as I can tell

every so often it does give me the spinning circle and then crash.

I have also reinstalled Xcode but nothing has changed

Macbook air 2017 -
macOS Big Sur (11.2.3) -
Xcode 12.4 (12d4e)

Comment: This would be a problem for Apple, not for us. File a bug report!

Comment: By the way, I dislike that "launch/splash screen" (it is actually called the Welcome To Xcode window). I suggest that the next time it appears you uncheck "Show this window when Xcode launches".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anybody else experiences this issue I will answer this question here.

This appears to be a bug with the Xcode launch screen for this version of Xcode.

My solution was to simply click the checkbox that says "show this window when Xcode launches" to turn that off

relaunch Xcode and open my project from the file menu.

Thanks `matt` for the suggestion :)

Comment: Yup, well, that would explain why I've never seen this problem — I've got that window turned off! :) But do file a bug.